# Pass string as uri parameter containing slashes or is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm having trouble with the ASP.NET Web API routing. Specifically I want to pass a string parameter that is either empty or containing a slash within the Uri. But unfortunately this breaks the routing.

I already have a proper route set up, which is matching fine if I have a normal string such as "fubar". I tried to pass the string url encoded, but this does not work. Apparently the problem is that some http sys layer is already decoding the string, meaning not `"fu%2fbar"` arrives, but `"fo/bar"` - which leads to another route.

Also when I pass an empty string the uri is `"api//..."`, the two `/` are merged and the segment is thrown away.

One method to solve the issue with the `/` inside is to double encode the Uri and decode it inside my method. But this seems like a very very bad option, so I'm looking for other methods on how I could solve this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make it a param that is accepted in the request body?

Comment: When I have a string as primary identifier for a resource it would not make sense to do so. Also having an optional filter query string shouldn't be in the body.

Answer (score 1):

For slashes you could prepare special routes

```
            "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}"
            "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}"
            "{controller}/{action}/{param1}"


    public ActionResult Index(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {
        string param = string.Concat(param1, param2, param3);
```

this way, fu and bar are two params.

Don't have any solution for empty strings. I would replace it in client app by space char or something else which means "empty" but is not

Comment: Sorry if I made myself unclear, but I want to pass _one_ string parameter that contains a slash, not two parameters. Your suggestion is not helping a bit with this case. I don't know what string the client exactly will send, so should I hold methods for an unlimited amount of strings? Also what if he'll send a "?", this would corrupt the routing too.

Comment: sure. i just suggest you a fast solution. if you need to manage all url special chars, just url encode, why is it a bad solution, it is made for your special problem. Otherwise, write your own routing module

Comment: Like I said, simple url encoding does not work. It gets decoded before it comes to routing, so a the encoding is pointless. An option would be double encode my string in the client and decode it inside the function again, but this seems like a very bad way. There must be something better.

Comment: I don't understand why it is the bad way. if we consider passing "/" and "?" in GET params is the good way, then url encoding is the good solutions. but maybe calling rest url with that kind of named resources is your problem

Comment: But Url Encoding does not work. The url will be decoded before the routing happens. This means whenever a url string parameter contains a "?" or a "/" char the routing will break, no matter if the string is encoded or not. So apparently my only options are to either double encode my url and decode it by hand inside my method, or to prevent the parameters to contain these chars in my client (and everything that relates to it). Both options are not acceptable, therefor I'm hoping and looking for a better solution.

Comment: @Kevin Nedelec. Your trick is awesome. It helps me in that situation when parameters are optional.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest either:

1. changing the request type to be POST and put the string into the body of the request
2. or add an interceptor (DelegatingHandler) which will grab the request and rewrite the param in the url, e.g. by replacing the invalid characters